# How to read txt files and import them into access table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am new to access vba. I am trying to find a way to import a txt file into my access db. I read a lot of articles and forums, and tested a lot of codes, but none of it worked. 
I was able to narrow down to the code- listed below. The problem that I have is that it runs and runs, and then I have close my db and start again. No error, just endless run. My txt file is not that big and it should not do this unless I have a bug in my code and I do not know how to fix it.
Please help.

```
Dim FileName As String
Dim MostRecentFile As String
Dim MostRecentDate As Date
Dim FileSpec As String
Dim filepath As String
Dim txtStream As Object
Dim strImportRecord As String

filepath = "\\C:\"
 FileSpec = "*.txt*"

FileName = Dir(filepath & FileSpec)

If FileName <> "" Then
    MostRecentFile = FileName
    MostRecentDate = FileDateTime(filepath & FileName)
    Do While FileName <> ""
        If FileDateTime(filepath & FileName) > MostRecentDate Then
             MostRecentFile = FileName
             MostRecentDate = FileDateTime(filepath & FileName)
        End If

       Loop
End If

Set txtStream = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(MostRecentFile)

Do While Not (txtStream.atendofstream)
        strImportRecord = txtStream.ReadAll
  Loop

DoCmd.TransferText acImportFixed, "myspecification", "mytable", "strImportRecord", False
```

Comment: Help docs indicate where you have "strImportRecord" should be a filename of the text file.  I'm not sure it can handle a text STRING.  try instead of looping through the file, to just replace the "strImportRecord" with the path to the desired text file. Also, please supply an example of the data in the text file and the current layout of the table.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code to ensure that its actually location the file?  Is it getting caught in the Loop reading the txtStream?  Is your file delimited? Have you manually imported the file already to create the import specification?

Comment: [Debugging VBA Code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) is very helpful.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your comment about replacing  "strImportRecord" with the filename of the text file and i need it to be a variable name.  Please expand on this....  I have imported this file manually before and it works just fine.  also I did go thru the code to see if the code sees the file and it does.  I will try to mock up  some text file for you and tbl layout.

Comment: `DoCmd.TransferText`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.transfertext

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Sub ImportMostRecentTextFile()

```
Dim FileName As String
Dim MostRecentFile As String
Dim MostRecentDate As Date
Dim FileSpec As String
Dim filepath As String
Dim txtStream As Object
Dim strImportRecord As String

filepath = "C:\Users\moone2\Documents\"
 FileSpec = "*.txt*"

FileName = Dir(filepath & FileSpec)

If FileName <> "" Then
    MostRecentFile = FileName
    MostRecentDate = FileDateTime(filepath & FileName)
    Do While FileName <> ""
        If FileDateTime(filepath & FileName) > MostRecentDate Then
             MostRecentFile = FileName
             MostRecentDate = FileDateTime(filepath & FileName)
        End If
        FileName = Dir()
       Loop
End If

'I don't think you need to load the text....
'------------
'Set txtStream = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(MostRecentFile)'
'
'Do While Not (txtStream.atendofstream)
'    strImportRecord = txtStream.ReadAll
'Loop
'
'Set txtStream = Nothing
'
'Debug.Print strImportRecord

'DoCmd.TransferText acImportFixed, "myspecification", "mytable", strImportRecord,
'---------------

'Just load from the most recent file, like this:
DoCmd.TransferText acImportFixed, "myspecification", "myTable", MostRecentFile, True
```

End Sub

Comment: Good to hear...Glad to help out.  Could you please mark this as the solution?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your loop to find the most recent file:

```
Do While FileName <> ""
```

never ends, because you never assign anything new to `FileName` in the loop.

You are missing a `FileName = Dir()` before `Loop`.

This won't be the only problem, all the things Mike wrote in his comments are correct.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my code and now db is giving me an error 53 - file not found and highlights this part: '''Set txtStream = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(MostRecentFile)'''

Comment: when error highlighted my code, I moved my cursor to  OpenText(MostRecentFile portion and it shows the file name that I would selected. It means that the code sees it, but for some reason says file not found.

Comment: Thank you everyone. Unfortunately, i still have an issue with this code. I tried to change my TransferText   syntax, but  when I put  "FileName" instead of  strImportRecord or MostRecentFile, the code says that file does not exist and gives me blank  when I hover over  this part. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @AccessNewbie thats because you need to include the path along with the filename.  The Dir() function is only going to return "file.txt". You need to combine it with the folder path. Like `"C:\Users\user\Documents\" & FileName`. Also to tack onto Andre's answer, to loop through the results from Dir(), just just FileName = Dir() WITHOUT a path and it will loop through the results found from the first call of that function. Otherwise you're not really iterating through the files i n the folder. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dir-function

Comment: Mike, I made some changes to my code,  FileName = Dir("\\C:\" & MostRecentFile) and   Set txtStream = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("\\C:\ & FileName). Now this code is running and running non stop. I do not know what to do. Is anyway possible you can send me the code how would you corrected it?